# Hyper-v internal lab and internet connection

Tags: networking, windows-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v, virtual-network

I have created and I am happily using a virtual lab with Hyper-V software on my Windows 8 professional.
The lab include four servers:

- Windows Server with Active Directory and DNS
- Windows Server with SQL Server 2012
- Windows Server with SharePoint 2013 server

All the servers have the following network configuration

**IP Address**: `192.168.10.x`
**Subnet Mask**: `255.255.255.0`

Everything works as expected. Now I need to make something to make the lab access the internet. By reading here and there I have found a [post](http://wordsideasandthings.blogspot.it/2013/01/hyper-v-internal-virtual-network-and.html) which explains how to setup the ICS.
I suspect however that this will not work in my case because the configuration of the IP address used by ICS which is in a different subnet (`192.168.137.1`).

How can I do to make the lab access the internet for windows updates?

Thanks

**EDIT**:
I have added a small simple diagram to explain the scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create another virtual switch which is external. Add another network interface to your devices and conect the external virtual switch. Just activate the network interface when you need to update so it won't interfere with your lab enviroment.